# Design for products with multiple sizes

Tags: database-design

How would you create a database that sells *products* of the same *cost* for each size range.

Current Products Table:

- Product 1 of 1mm
- Product 1 of 2mm
- Product 1 of 3mm
- Etc up to 1000mm

Does it make sense to store it as mentioned above?

Or would you you store it as:

- Product 1, minimum length 1mm, maximum length 1000mm

Each sale line will mention the exact size sold.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one would do something like the second option you mentioned, with a dedicated dimension field for the `Size` and another field for the `UnitOfMeasure` (or `UM` for short). Or possibly refactoring those fields into a separate `ProductDimensions` table (though this is more optional / use case dependent).

This provides the most flexibility, and makes the most sense logically for the purpose of a `Products` table, as one would assume the table would store *unique* `Products`. Otherwise, seeing `Product1` (etc) multiple times in the `Products` table could be confusing and / or complicate application logic.